# What are some .NET methods for creating a generic SQL Server query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I'm just looking to write a generic function in C# .NET 4.0 where I can send it a database string, a query string, and get my results back.

Not being that well versed in C# and it's various different objects, I'm not really sure what the best options might be for returning this information.

I know there is `DataTable`, `DataSet`, and that's really about it. What I'm looking for is an object that is fairly efficient and something where I can easily access it's data members. I'm sure it wouldn't be a problem writing my own, but I know there has to be some other object in .NET 4.0 that I can access.

Comment: Let me get this right - you want to send user-defined queries to your database? You've thought about all the security vulnerabilities this would open up, right?

Comment: No, I want to write a generic function to store in a class so I don't have to retype the connection information over and over hundreds of times. I just want something I can send my query string, what database I want to access, and get my information back. Sorry, if I was unclear.

Comment: are you storing your connection string in the app.config(web.config for websites)?  This lets you using the ConfigurationManager class like ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseServer"].ConnectionString

Comment: Put it in a resource / config file , a singleton, even a member variable. Something like public DataTable GetSomeData(Connection,SQL), sounds like a good idea at first, but unless it's some sort of internal noddy tool, that itsn't going to change, it will turn into a bad one quick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with such a design is that it's very difficult to use best practices for security and preventing SQL Injection.  Passing in a pure SQL statement to a function pretty much eliminates the ability to defend against SQL Injection unless you do it carefully.

As a general rule, if you're taking in *any* user input, you want to be sure that you're either using [parameterized stored procedures](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_2%3a_Stored_Procedures), or [parameterized queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1%3a_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29).  The recommended pattern would be to pass in a statement and an array of type object that contains  the correct number of parameter values, and build the parameter collection in your function.

We use the [Microsoft data Application Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664408%28PandP.50%29.aspx) from their patterns and Practices library, which contain functionality that really makes this a lot easier.

In using this, the ConnectionString is stored in the app.config or web.config, and you pass in the NAME of the connection string,  The Data Application Blocks code takes care of looking it up, creating the command, connection, and performing the query.

Our code looks like this when using this pattern:

```
public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(string CallingApp, string ConnectionStringName, string StoredProcName, object[] ParameterValues)
{
        DataSet ReturnValue = new DataSet();

        Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database db = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ConnectionStringName);
        try
        {
            ReturnValue = db.ExecuteDataSet(StoredProcName, ParameterValues);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // a bunch of code for exception handling removed            
        }


        return ReturnValue;
 }
```

This is the code for getting a DataSet. There are plenty of other functions available, and this code might not work against the newest version of the Data Access Library.  We're using a slightly older version, but this should give you an idea of how easy it is to use.

Comment: Very detailed, answered my question, and gave me a starting point to do more research. A better answer isn't possible I don't think.

Answer (score 2):

New and improved method is not to do that, but to havea method to get the data you want.

E.g define a `CustomerOrder` class. Have a database module with a function called say:

```
GetOpenOrdersForCustomer(int argCustomerID)
```

that returns you a collection of them.

Look up Entity Framework POCO etc.

`DataSet` and `DataTable` are earlier incarnations of this sort of thing, they are pretty hefty, with a lot of baggage.

If you want/need to do a bit more handcoding. Interfaces like `IDataReader`, `IDbCommand` `IDbConnection`, will isolate you from a number of implementation details in your code, for instance whether your backend is SQL Server, MySql etc.

Even then you are still better off not passing things like `DataTable`, `SqlCommand` about about in your application code.

Too many chances to to plaster the database schema all over the code leaving you with a huge and soon to be realised potential for technical debt.

Hide it all.  In Code First POCO it's practically invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using an ORM like NHibernate : http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx

It will do everything related to database and you will be working with nice object classes.

In other case, your function can return Datatable and you can write another function to get the DataTable and extract data into an object class. eg. This new function would be like,

public object PopulateData(DataTable table, Enum ClassType); //Or something similar

You can then use reflection to map DataTable columns and class object.

But I would recommend using an ORM.

Answer (score 1):

It depends the scenario you want to cover.
For example, in an MVC application its fairly maintainable to deploy a data layer based on Entity Framework, because its easily testeable and the communication with the database is very straightforward through simple objects.

Another approach could be use an already developed component, such is Data Application Block from Enterprise library or perhaps develop your custom database factory... It just depends the purpose of your development.

Could you give more details of what kind of application we are talking about?. It's an existing database or a new one?.

Another question. What exactly you want to expect to pass over the query string?. If you mind pass sql sentences i will tell you that its a very bad and dangerous practice that you should avoid.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like:

```
public static DbDataReader Query(
    string connectionString, string selectCommand, 
    params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] parameters)
{
    var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    var command = new OleDbCommand(selectCommand, connection);

    foreach (var p in parameters)
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(p.Key, p.Value));

    var result = command.ExecuteReader();
    return result;
}
```

OleDb used as example.